# Outputcache is not created on server side request

Tags: asp.net, webforms, outputcache

I have a webform called Page.aspx with an OutputCache directive, with VaryByParam=* attribute.

Pages are created server side, with an ID attribute. So when the first user hits Page.aspx?ID={???} the cache is created.

I don't want to wait a user to hit the page to create the cache anymore. So I tried to make an HttpRequest as soon as a new Page is created with the following code:

```
    private void CreatePageOutputCache(Int32 pageId)
    {
        String link = "Page.aspx?ID="+pageId.ToString();
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(link);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();            
    }
```

However, the cache is not created when called like this. Only when the request is made from a Browser. Is there a way of doing this?